# Woocommerce tables don't get deleted even plugin is removed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Today I installed a few plugins: GD Rating Systems, WooCommerce, WooCommerce and Booking and Rental. Those installations created a number of tables in the database:

`wp_gdrts_itemmeta`, `wp_gdrts_items`, `wp_gdrts_logmeta`, `wp_gdrts_logs`, `wp_hotel_booking_order_itemmeta`, `wp_hotel_booking_order_items`, `wp_hotel_booking_plans`, `wp_woocommerce_api_keys`, `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`, `wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions`, `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`, `wp_woocommerce_order_items`, `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta`, `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens`, `wp_woocommerce_sessions`, `wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations`, `wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods`, `wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones`, `wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations`, `wp_woocommerce_tax_rates`

But when I deleted those plugins from admin, tables did not get deleted. Is it safe to remove above tables manually going inside the database? And if I do not delete them can it create any problem later?

I am very new to WordPress. What can I try next?

My version of WordPress is 4.7.2

Answer (score 3):

It is default functionality of `WooCommerce` as mentioned in their documentation. You can add the below code in `wp-config.php` to delete WC data when the plugin is removed.

```
define( 'WC_REMOVE_ALL_DATA', true);
```

Refer the below URL of `WooCommerce` documentation.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installing-uninstalling-woocommerce/

Answer (score 2):

Normally, all the databases created by WoooCommerce himself are delete if you uninstall the plugin from WordPress. You can see the "drop table" and tables list in this file : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/uninstall.php (line 51), load on uninstall.

Maybe you had a problem on your uninstall, try it again (install / uninstall Woocommerce, not just desactivate) if you can.

For the other plugins, unfortunately all developers do not handle tables deletions. If you no longer use any plugins and dependency associated with WooCoomerce, you can remove these tables without worries.

Don't forget to make a back-up before that.

Hope I will help!